# Digest Authentication for IIS7 + SvnBridge

Tags: iis-7, authentication

I'm trying to install SvnBridge on my TFS Server running Windows Server 2008 R2, TFS, and now SvnBridge in an IIS7 website.

http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/

When I attempted to visit the project repository for example @ `http://<mywebserver.domain.com>:8081/repository_name`

I am prompted for an authentication. I cannot figure out how to add a user for this authentication? None of my logins or IIS-User logins work? Can anyone point me to the correct location of a guide to adding users for Digest Authentication.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Did you ever figure it out? I have played with enabling/disabling every possible authentication type for the SVNbridge site in IIS, all with no luck.

Comment: *No* not yet, I went on the '[Codeplex](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/discussions/248815)' for the project - someone suggested that I default to 'Basic Authentication' but I can't figure out how to use add a USER for Basic Authentication via IIS -- I don't feel very smart! I can connect but I can't authenticate so it's pretty much useless at this point!